# eBay Browse API limiting the number of category_ids to 1, but documentation says you can add multiple category_ids

Tags: ebay-api

When performing a GET request to the eBay browse API I am getting the following error message:

```
<class 'list'>: [{'errorId': 12030, 'domain': 'API_BROWSE', 'category': 'REQUEST', 'message': 'The number of categories in the request has exceeded the limit. Please reduce the number of categories to 1 or less.', 'parameters': [{'name': 'allowedMaxCategories', 'value': '1'}]}]
```

Here is the URL of the request I am trying to make:

[https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search?category_ids=58058,11700,293,15032,1249,625&filter=sellers:{foo}&limit=100&sort=newlyListed](https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search?category_ids=58058,11700,293,15032,1249,625&filter=sellers:%7Bfoo%7D&limit=100&sort=newlyListed)

However, the documentation for the Browse API suggests that you can pass category_ids as a string array separated by commas.

> The category ID is used to limit the results. This field can have one category ID or a comma separated list of IDs.

Here is a link to the documenation for the Browse API:

https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/browse/resources/item_summary/methods/search#h2-input

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code in eBay api explorer, i received warning response of your defined filters not category, after corrected filters i received success response with records.

Check this query

```
https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search?category_ids=58058,11700,293,15032,1249,625&limit=100&sort=newlyListed&filter=sellers:%7Bfoo%7D
```

**NOTE:** the seller `foo` not found so return success with 0 record but without seller or a valid seller id return success with records

Comment: I have never used the eBay sandbox before, but searching using the sandbox only returns sellers with the username ```testuser_pa4_demo_<>``` It does not allow you to search using real sellers. Did you search using real sellers or not?

Comment: @user13834264, yes i have tested in production and sandbox both are not same, if you use sandbox with real sandbox userid its working with multiple categories but in production multiple category_ids not allowed same error returned as you reported above,  because ebay mentioned this note.
`**Note:** Currently, you can pass in only one category ID per request.`

Comment: My issue is that I was unsuccessful in using real user IDs in the sandbox environment though. Are you certain you used real IDs in the sandbox environment? If so, which of the regional eBay Sites did it work on? I would appreciate it if you could send me the full request including the seller name & site ID, please.

Comment: You cannot use real production information in sandbox, i have tested sandbox query with sandbox user and token, and production query with production user and token. i cant share user information because its privacy issue sorry for that.